# Combine two integers into one and decode them later

Tags: c++, integer

Using C++ I need to combine two distinct IDs into one 16bit integer. Then later on I need to decode this 16bit integer into the two original ID values.

Example:

```
// Store two integers into one
unsigned short Identifier1 = 12793; //(maximum number 30000)
unsigned short Identifier1 = 5450; //(maximum number 30000)
unsigned short CombinedIDs = 34283; // this is example, I don't know the code for that

// Decode one integer into two
// At this point I only have CombinedIDs value, I need to extract it
// into the two original IDs

unsigned short OriginalIdentifier1 = ...CombinedIDs.. code to get 12793
unsigned short OriginalIdentifier2 = ...CombinedIDs.. code to get 5450
```

Comment: Information theory tells us that this is impossible in the general case. If your identifiers have maximum values of 30000, then they require 15 bits each to store. Together, they contan 30 bits of information. You can't compress 30 bits of information into a 16-bit integer.

Comment: I'd consider using a 32-bit result if you need a 30k max.

Comment: It's not a homework. I need to store two IDs into a 16bit integer - 2 bytes that is located on a certain palce in an IP packet.

Comment: @MarcusFrenkel: Still not possible. Maximum number of 100 needs 7 bits, 30000 needs 15 bits. Together that's 22 bits, still more than 16.

Comment: It'd be nice if this were possible, since by repeated application of the principle, any computer would be able to get by with just one word of storage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is impossible.

Assuming your two identifiers can be in the range `[0, 30000]`, there are 30000 x 30000 = ~2^30 possible pairs of identifiers. However, there are only 2^16 possible 16-bit numbers. So, you can't possibly map pairs of identifiers to a 16-bit integer and expect to recover the identifiers from it.

---

Instead, you can use a 32-bit integer to store the combination, in which case both encoding and decoding is straightforward:

Encoding:

```
unsigned short Identifier1 = 12793;
unsigned short Identifier2 = 5450;
unsigned int CombinedIDs = (Identifier1 << 16) | Identifier2;
```

Decoding:

```
unsigned short Identifier1 = CombinedIDs >> 16;
unsigned short Identifier2 = CombinedIDs & 0x0000FFFF
```

Note that now the restriction that the identifiers be in the range [0, 30000] is not necessary - they be any unsigned short value.

---

**EDIT** Answering your comment: 4 and 12 bits are possible.

Encoding:

```
unsigned short Identifier1;  // 4 bits
unsigned short Identifier2;  // 12 bits
unsigned short CombinedIDs = (Identifier1 << 12) | Identifier2;
```

Decoding:

```
unsigned short Identifier1 = CombinedIDs >> 12;
unsigned short Identifier2 = CombinedIDs & 0x0FFF;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to combine 4bit and 12bit integer into one and decode it later? If it's not possible then at least the case of two 8bit integers. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't combine two numbers less than 30000 and stuff it into a 16 bit decimal.

To be able to express 30,000 unique possible values, you need at least 15 bits (2^15 is 32,768).

If you have to choose two numbers with each 30,000 unique possible values, the total number of possibilities are 900,000,000, which requires at least 30 bits (2^30 is 1,073,741,824).

Try using an int.

```
unsigned short Identifier1 = 29999;
unsigned short Identifier2 = 1;
unsigned int combined = identifier1<<16 + identifier2;

unsigned short extracted1 = (combined & 0xffff0000)>>16;
unsigned short extracted2 = combined & 0xffff;
```

Comment: Thank you. The previous reply came first so I need to accept that one.