# Combine 2 (signed) Integers into one

Tags: java, integer, bit-shift

Using android java i need to combine/decode 2 integers, where the 2nd one can be signed. First integer is unsigned 0-4 (4 bit) and the second integer is reaching from -128 to max 99.
For that i am using the operations descriped by HighCommander4 here:
[Combine two integers into one and decode them later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039335/combine-two-integers-into-one-and-decode-them-later)

For example, combine

```
int id1 = 1;
int id2 = 20; // gives combined = 276
```

This is the easy thing using HighCommander4s solution.
But how to do it with signed integers like:

```
int id1 = 1;
int id2 = -128; // gives combined = -384
```

Right now based on the solution linked above i created the following functions:

```
public static int encodeInt(int key, int value) {
    return ((key << 8) | (value < 0 ? value * -1 : value)) * (value < 0 ? -1 : 1);
}
public static int decodeInt1(int combined) {
    return combined < 0 ? (combined * -1) >> 8 : combined >> 8;
}
public static int decodeInt2(int combined) {
    return combined < 0 ? ((combined * -1) & 0xFF) * -1 : combined & 0xFF;
}
```

I am not very familar with bit shift operations, so i think there will be a better way to combine signed integers?

Best regards,
Juergen

Comment: why `value * -1`? Simply `-value` is enough and easier to read

Answer (score 0):

This is what i got after some tests, assuming positive integers don't exceed 127 and negative integers are not less than -128:

```
public static int encodeInt(int key, int value) {
    return (key << 8) | (value < 0 ? value + 256 : value);
}
public static int decodeInt1(int combined) {
    return combined >> 8;
}
public static int decodeInt2(int combined) {
    combined &= 0xFF;
    return combined < 128 ? combined : combined - 256;
}
```

That produces:

```
encodeInt(0, 0) // 0
encodeInt(0, 20) // 20
encodeInt(0, 127) // 127
encodeInt(0, -128) // 128

encodeInt(1, 0) // 256
encodeInt(1, 20) // 276
encodeInt(1, 127) // 383
encodeInt(1, -128) // 384
```

and so on...
Works only on integer ranges -128 - +127 since +128 will be transformed into -128 on decodeInt2.

Is that a good approach?